# How do i implement Security and User Authentication in Node JS Socket Server when integrated with Java based LMS system?

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

I need to integrate NodeJS with Socket server to an existing LMS application for building a real time event based system. 
The LMS system is java based and it maintains all the user details. When the users are logged into the LMS and from the LMS Web pages, it will initiate Socket IO Client call to the Socket Server.

I want to introduce the security and authentication mechanism for the Socket Server. I don't want anyone to connect directly to the Socket Server

1. i.e. the Socket Server should accept connections only from the specified LMS System.
2. I need to introduce a user authentication mechanism during the handshake between LMS and Socket Server.

I am thinking of sending some sort of encrypted token from the Java system to the Socket Server, and the Socket Server should be able to decrypt and get the username from the token during handshake. 
How do i achieve this?

Comment: One thing I looked into, but have not got the fibres straight together, is https://www.npmjs.org/package/js-nacl , it is the same encryption as used by http://threema.org. (http://nacl.cr.yp.to/ for the cryptographs' homepage.)

Comment: If you really wanted to use the handshake for that, you get into trouble...haha, no, you needed to change the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure *red field*.